# How do I keep Screenshot open to take multiple screenshots?

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, screenshot, presentation

I wish to take multiple screenshots to put into a presentation, but the Screenshot application closes after each area selection screenshot. How do I take multiple screenshots without the application closing each time?

(This feature is available in Windows 10's Snippet tool, so I expect it to exist in Ubuntu.)

Comment: I thought a workaround would be 'gnome-screenshot -c -a -d 5' in terminal, but I am met with the error, "Conflicting options: --area and --delay should not be used at the same time.". I do not understand why these options are regarded as conflicting; it seemed better than using the Screenshot GUI, since I could just up-arrow, Enter to repeat ...

Answer (score 6):

There's also a [list of keyboard shortcuts you can utilize](https://itsfoss.com/take-screenshot-linux/):

<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> **Save** a screenshot of the **entire screen**
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> **Save** a screenshot of a **specific region**
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> **Save** a screenshot of the current **window**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> **Copy** the screenshot of the **entire screen** to the clipboard
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>  **Copy** the screenshot of a **specific region** to the clipboard
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>  **Copy** the screenshot of the current **window** to the clipboard

Comment: these worked great for me on linuxmint. how come this doesnt have more likes? super useful

Comment: Edit: on newer installation of linuxmint, It works great for me as well

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like Screenshot can do that, but you can use **shutter** instead:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

UPDATE 2020-08-14: In Ubuntu 20.04 Screenshot can take multiple screenshots.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as of 18.10, https://itsfoss.com/install-shutter-ubuntu/

Comment: `Ubuntu 20.04 Screenshot can take multiple screenshots` How?  I failed to find this option.

Comment: @Tino After capturing, click the back button (the "<" button) on the top left corner of the Screenshot app to take a new capture.

Comment: @bennylp How do I keep the window open?  It immediately closes.  No window, no back-button.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal, `man gnome-screenshot` to learn about the command; `gnome-screenshot -i` to quickly open the Screenshot GUI; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (within Terminal) to terminate the process after copying the screenshot to clipboard; <kbd>up arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quickly execute the command again for another screenshot. This saves time compared to opening Screenshot from Launcher each time.

Comment: Or run infinite loop with gnome-screenshot in terminal `while true; do gnome-screenshot -i; done`.